# Spark SQL long double values are coming with Exponential

Tags: java, function, apache-spark-sql

I have a `amount` value, which we are reading from a file and trying to print on the console.

When we try to print, it is showing as `Exponential` and another issue is when we try to cast it is coming as `null`.

Input value:

```
{"amt":987654321111.0}
```

**Sample Code:**

```
df.show();
df.registerTempTable("input");
DataFrame outputDF = sqlContext.sql("select cast(amt as decimal) from input");
outputDF.show();
```

**Output:**

```
+----------------+
|             amt|
+----------------+
|9.87654321111E11|
+----------------+

root
 |-- amt: double (nullable = true)

root
 |-- amt: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)

+----+
| amt|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue using `StructType` createDecimalType method.

```
StructType schema = new StructType().add("amt", DataTypes.createDecimalType(38,10));

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().schema(schema).json("test.json");
```